# How to find $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}j(1-p)^j$?

Tags: limits

How to prove $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}j(1-p)^j=\frac{1-p}{p^2}$?

Is there any general ways to think about this kind of problems?

Comment: You might be able to get at this problem by finding where the sum converges. You could then relate what you are summing to the derivative of a sum that you know.

Comment: If the sum $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty f_i(x)$ converges uniformly, then $\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i = 1}^\infty f_i(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}f_i(x)$.

Comment: $$|1-p| < 1 {}{}{}{}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n=\frac {1}{1-x} \ ,|x| < 1$$
Then take the derivative and multiply by $x$ to get your sum.

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{j=1}^{n} j(1-p)^j=1(1-p)+2(1-p)^2+3(1-p)^3+...+n(1-p)^n$$

Multiply by $1-p$

$$(1-p)S=1(1-p)^2+2(1-p)^3+3(1-p)^4+...+n(1-p)^{n+1}$$

$$S-(1-p)S=1(1-p)+1(1-p)^2+...+1(1-p)^n+n(1-p)^{n+1}$$

$$pS=(1-p)\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{1-(1-p)}+n(1-p)^{n+1}=$$

$$S=\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{p}+\frac{n(1-p)^{n+1}}{p}$$

Now make $n \rightarrow \infty$. If you have $|1-p|<1$ then your sum will go to:

$$\left(\frac{1-p}{p^2}\right)$$

> P.S: You can use the same idea for a sum like:
>
> $$S=a_1g_1+a_2g_2+...+a_ng_n$$
>
> where $a_n$ is an arithmetic sequence and $g_n$ is a geometric sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see this as a two geometric series when you write out the terms, so under assumption of convergence you can reorder and calculate (using geometric series formula where appropriate):
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}j(1-p)^j &= (1-p) + [(1-p)^2+(1-p)^2] + [(1-p)^3+(1-p)^3+(1-p)^3] + \dots \\
&= [(1-p) + (1-p)^2 + \dots] +[(1-p)^2 + (1-p)^3 + \dots] + \dots \\
&= \frac{1-p}{1-(1-p)} +  \frac{(1-p)^2}{1-(1-p)} + \dots\\
&= \frac{1}{p} ((1-p) +  (1-p)^2 + \dots)\\
&= \frac{1}{p} \left(\frac{1-p}{1-(1-p)}\right)\\
&= \frac{1-p}{p^2}\\
\end{align}